# Working with flutter and just encountered the following error that says invalid range value

Tags: flutter, dart

[error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT1NT.png)//below is the main file of my flutter project . in the main dart I am passing favourite_meal to //the favourite_screen, However it gives me an error rangeerror (index) invalid value valid value //range is empty 0 .. error it shows comes from route section where i register my routes when i //pass favourites_meal to  '/': (ctx) => tabScreen(favourite_meals),

```
import 'package:meals_app/dummy_data.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/filters.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/meal_screen.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/models/meals.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/tabs_screen.dart';
import 'tabs_screen.dart';
import '/categories_meals_screen.dart';
import '/categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, bool> filters = {
    'gluten': false,
    'lactose': false,
    'vegetarian': false,
    'vegan': false
  };

  List<Meal> available_meals = DUMMY_MEALS;

  List<Meal> favourite_meals = [];

  void setfilters(Map<String, bool> filterData) {
    setState(() {
      filters = filterData;
      available_meals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
        if (filters['gluten'] == true && !meal.isGlutenFree) {
          return false;
        }
        if (filters['lactose'] == true && !meal.isLactoseFree) {
          return false;
        }

        if (filters['vegetarian'] == true && !meal.isVegetarian) {
          return false;
        }
        if (filters['vegan'] == true && !meal.isVegan) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  void togglefavourites(String mealId) {
    final existing_index =
        favourite_meals.indexWhere((meal) => meal.id == mealId);

    if (existing_index >= 0) {
      setState(() {
        favourite_meals
            .removeAt(existing_index); //if returns -1 no index exists
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        favourite_meals.add(
          DUMMY_MEALS.firstWhere((meal) => meal.id == mealId),
        );
      }); //look in dummy meals and return that index -add to favourite meals
    }
  }

  bool ismealFav(String id) {
    return favourite_meals.any((meal) => meal.id == id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Meals App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            bodyText1: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 1, 1),
            ),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 1, 1),
            ),
            subtitle1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontFamily: 'Raleway',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      // home: CategoriesScreen(),
      routes: {
        '/': (ctx) => tabScreen(favourite_meals),
        '/category-meals': (ctx) => CategoriesMealScreen(available_meals),
        mealdetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
            mealdetailScreen(togglefavourites, ismealFav),
        filter_screen.route_name: (ctx) => filter_screen(setfilters, filters),
      },
//   onGenerateRoute:(settings){
//     print(settings.arguments);
//     return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx)=>CategoriesScreen(),);
// } ,
      onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (ctx) => CategoriesScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

// this is the screen where I am passing down the favourites meal list from main file.I have //tried flutter clean but still no luck . the listview builder isgetting the itemcount.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/meals_item.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/models/meals.dart';

class FavouritesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Meal> thefavourites;
  FavouritesScreen(this.thefavourites);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (thefavourites.isEmpty == true) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('No Favourites'),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return MealItem(
            id: thefavourites[index].id,
            title: thefavourites[index].title,
            Duration: thefavourites[index].duration,
            imgurl: thefavourites[index].imageUrl,
            affordability: thefavourites[index].affordability,
            complexity: thefavourites[index].complexity,
          );
        },
        itemCount: thefavourites.length,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First off try to set the `itemCount` for the `ListView.builder` above the `itemBuilder`. Set it to `thefavourites.length`. Also add some optional values to your object variables like `thefavourites[index].complexity ?? 'Something Here'`. You find out what object is null.

Comment: I did add item count above it but to no avail .. it is still giving me the same error and honestly i Dont know what is causing that